# How to fix images floating over navbar while scrolling?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, gallery

Long story short, I've been working on this site for my exam. Everything was good until I started making a gallery. The problem isn't the gallery itself, it's the navbar, I have no idea how can i fix this. Anyways, when I scroll down to my gallery the photos don't just hide under the navbar, they go over it. Same thing happens for the jumbotron that I have, the text goes over it as well.

Here's my HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown"> Daugiau </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> ****** </a>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item yes">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> ****** </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> ****** </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><s> ****** </s></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="gal">
    <div class=" text-center py-3">
        <h5> ... </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 mb-4">
                <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                    <img src="******.jpg" class="img-fluid"
                        alt="">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                    <img src="******.jpg" class="img-fluid"
                        alt="">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                    <img src="******.jpg" class="img-fluid"
                        alt="">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 mb-4">
                <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                    <img src="******.jpg" class="img-fluid"
                        alt="">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                    <img src="******.jpg" class="img-fluid"
                        alt="">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                    <img src="******" class="img-fluid"
                        alt="">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" text-center py-3">
        <button class="clearbtn" type="button" onclick="daugiau1()"> ****** </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('index_jt.jpg');
  height:300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: transform .2s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  transition: transform .2s;
} 
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black !important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
}
.nav-item {
    transition: transform .2s;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

I know it's a lot but I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what i have understand from your post is that, you want your gallery section to be under nav-bar while scrolling,for that add following css:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
```